# How do I fix this Lego character Rig in Blender 2.8?

Tags: rigging

I'm making a lego character but the rigging of the leg is messed up. I tried my best to fix it but so far no luck. Is there any way to fix this?

[image: Lego character with leg with a unwanted bulge]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Those 4 vertices just stay in place? adding with automatic weights doesnt always work properly, you just have to add those 4 vertices to the corresponding bone vertex group.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I can send you my character file to you through email to see if you can take a closer look and if you can fix it try it and then tell me what you did in steps in order for those vertices to move with the others when the leg moves when i use Footroll.r bone

Comment: you can attach ur blend file https://blend-exchange.com and then edit ur post to include the code snippet it generates

Comment: Never mind i fixed it turns out it was assigned to the wieghts to the left foot but i took it off and now it can move properly

Comment: Actually i have another problem so i will send you the file first then i will tell you the problem

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=8XbQD3GN" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/8XbQD3GN/)

Comment: Ok the leg are is now fixed but the area alittle crooked and doesnt match with the other leg. do i need reinput the wieghts